# How to set 2 rightNavigationButtons programmly

Tags: ios, swift

I have a navigation button, here is code:

```
func barItem() {
    let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
    button.setTitle("Watch AR", for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(openAR), for: .touchUpInside)
    button.setTitleColor(.orange, for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(.gray, for: .highlighted)
    button.sizeToFit()
    
    self.navigationItem.setRightBarButton(UIBarButtonItem(customView: button), animated: true);
}
```

Then, I am trying to add one more navigation buttons in `viewDidLoad` method

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.backgroundColor = .white
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.orange
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Add", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(savePicture))
    self.barItem()
}
```

But it is not working, why?

Comment: Use `setRightBarButtonItems(_:animated:)` instead. Retrieve the current rightBarButtonItem if it's already present, and add the new one to the array...

Answer (score 0):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()        
    let barButton1 = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Button 1", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(barButtonItem1))        
    let barButton2 = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Button 2", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(barButtonItem2))        
    self.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItems([barButton1, barButton2], animated: true)        
}
    
@objc func barButtonItem1(){
    
}

@objc func barButtonItem2(){
    
}
```